# How to hide checkbox label by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox, jquery-events

Have 2 identical blocks of code:

```
<label class="checkbox-body chkpositive tags-block mb-5">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$tag->id}}" name="tags[]">
  <div id="checkbox" class="checkbox-block"></div>
  <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">{{$tag->name}} ({{$tag->films->count()}})</p>
</label>
```

```
<label class="checkbox-body chknegative tags-block mb-5" value="{{$tag->id}}">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$tag->id}}" name="notags[]" id="chknegative">
  <div id="checkbox" class="checkbox-block"></div>
  <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">{{$tag->name}}</p>
</label>
```

They are different only in name of label classes **chkpositive** and **chknegative**, and input names

They are responsible for showing of tags which must placed in process of choise films. I need to do so that when press on tag from block **chkpositive** tag with identical value in block **chknegative** dissapeared. And vice versa when press on tag from block **chknegative** to disappear identical tag from **chkpositive**. By method "toggle" for example.

I wanted to do this with javascript and jQuery, but haven't a success. Can this issue have a simple solutions?

12 hours find for a solutions, try many codes, saw analogs with google, but don't found. Came to the conclusion that I need something similar, but working:

```
$(function() {
    $(".chkpositive input").click(function(event) {
        var x = $(this).is(':checked').value;
        if (x == true) {
            $(this).value.(".chknegative").hide();
        } else {
            $(this).value.(".chknegative").show();
        }
    });
  });

$(function() {
    $(".chknegative input").click(function(event) {
        var x = $(this).is(':checked').value;
        if (x == true) {
            $(this).value.(".chkpositive ").hide();
        } else {
            $(this).value.(".chkpositive ").show();
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please add the additional details provided as comments directly to your question, along with some example *rendered* HTML (**without** `{{ }}` server side tags) that shows how this works in practice.   Doesn't sound overly more complicated than my answer, but existing code (HTML) is easier to provide code (js) for than your wording. See [mcve].

Comment: For you example you state *"your code deleted all the block .. my goal that deletes only these tags, which values are duplicated in other block"*, yet in the question you clearly state "*Have **two** [identical] blocks of code"* - so there only being two blocks, there can't be "all the block[s]".

Comment: I mean this: `@foreach($tags as $tag)
        @if($count <10)
        <label class="checkbox-body chkpositive tags-block mb-5">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="$tag->id" name="tags[]">
  <div id="checkbox" class="checkbox-block"></div>
  <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">$tag->name ($tag->films->count())</p>
</label>
            @php($count++)
        @endif
    @endforeach`  this is the block with all tags in loop. Same structure have negative block. Both of them have similar tags with similar values. In total, each block has 85 tags.

Comment: And I want click to input in one block that dissapear the same input (with right same value) in other block.

Comment: You probably want: `$(".chknegative[value='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))`   **edit** fixed typo

Comment: Exatly. This works how I wanted)) Thank you wery much!! How can I add score to your reputation?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea.

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

returns a boolean, so there's no `.value`, and

```
$(this).value.(".chknegative").hide()
```

should be just

```
$(".chknegative").hide()
```

For hide/show, the `if (isTrue) hide else show` can be replaced with a single `toggle(isTrue)`

Giving:

```js
$(".chkpositive input").click(function(event) {
  $(".chknegative").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))
});
$(".chknegative input").click(function(event) {
  $(".chkpositive").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="checkbox-body chkpositive tags-block mb-5">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="tags[]">
  <div class="checkbox-block"></div>
  <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">Yes, 55</p>
</label>
<label class="checkbox-body chknegative tags-block mb-5" value="{{$tag->id}}">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$tag->id}}" name="notags[]" id="chknegative">
  <div class="checkbox-block"></div>
  <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">No</p>
</label>
```

Now, it's unclear if you have a single pair of positive/negative or if these are in rows / multiple values.  If you have multiple, the easiest option is to wrap them, then you can use

```
$(this).closest("wrapper").find(".chknegative")`
```

instead of `$(".chknegative")` which will find all of them across all rows.

Updated snippet for multiple +ve/-ve pairs:

```js
$(".chkpositive input").click(function(event) {
  $(this).closest(".chkwrapper").find(".chknegative").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))
});
$(".chknegative input").click(function(event) {
  $(this).closest(".chkwrapper").find(".chkpositive").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```css
p.constructor_checkbox-text { display:inline-block; }
.chkwrapper + .chkwrapper { border-top:1px solid rebeccapurple }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='chkwrapper'>
  <label class="checkbox-body chkpositive tags-block mb-5">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="tags[]">
    <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">Yes, 55</p>
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-body chknegative tags-block mb-5" value="{{$tag->id}}">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$tag->id}}" name="notags[]">
    <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">No</p>
  </label>
</div>
<div class='chkwrapper'>
  <label class="checkbox-body chkpositive tags-block mb-5">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="tags[]">
    <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">Yes, 55</p>
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-body chknegative tags-block mb-5" value="{{$tag->id}}">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$tag->id}}" name="notags[]">
    <p class="constructor_checkbox-text">No</p>
  </label>
</div>
```

(be sure not to duplicate any IDs)

---

**EDIT**

In the case where there's more than one, you can match them using the `name` attribute, eg:

```
$(".chknegative[name=" + this.value + "])"
```

Such as:

```
$(".chknegative[value='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))
```

In this case, you may also want to check the related +ve (or -ve) checkboxes as well.

eg if you have 3 +ves and 3 -ves for "valueX" and tick any of +ves, then hide the 3 -ves and tick the remaining 2 +ves, eg:

```
// when positive clicked
$(".chkpositive input").click(function(event) {

  // show/hide negatives
  $(".chknegative[value='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'))

  // also tick/untick matching positives
  $(".chkpositive[value='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

Comment: Thank you wery much for your extended answer, but unfortunately each query based on values of each tag. This is means, that used by your code deleted all the block negative or positive, with all tags in this block. But my goal that deletes only these tags, which values are duplicated in other block. In other words if somebody clicked to input with value=42 in positive block, automatically is dissapear label-input from negative block with the same value.

Comment: All of values in negative and positive block are from one table and mean the same thing, only interpreted from the position or inclusion in the search query or exclusion. For the full clarifying situation you can place the page with blocks here flobex.net/tags (top block is positive and bottom block "Remove films" is negative). if you wish of course